# Api platform->ApiResource->operations->new Get error : There is no builtin action for the operation

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I use Api PLatform 3.1 & Symfony 6 and I created a custom operation which works, the operation return an array with all the results :

```
#[ApiResource(
    description: "Roll the dices",
    operations: [
        new Get(
            name: 'setrolldices',
            uriTemplate: '/sets/{id}/roll',
            uriVariables:[
                'id' => new Link(
                    fromClass: Set::class
                )
            ],
            requirements: ['id' => '\d+'],
            controller: SetRollDicesController::class,
            openapi: new Model\Operation(
                summary: 'Roll the dices !!!', 
                description: 'Get a random value of each dice', 
                responses: [
                    '200!!!' => new Model\Response(
                        description: "Dices value",
                        content: new \ArrayObject([
                            'application/json' => [
                                'schema' => [
                                    'type' => 'array',
                                    'description' => 'The value each dice'
                                ],
                                'example' => [
                                    1,2,3,4
                                ]
                            ]
                        ])
                    )
                ]
            )
        ),
    ]
)]
```

and I would like to create more operation for the same entity but if I add the following operation I have a fatal error : There is no builtin action for the "setbestdices" operation. You need to define the controller yourself in . (which is being imported from "/apiplatform/config/routes/api_platform.yaml"). Make sure there is a loader supporting the "api_platform" type.

```
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new Get(
            name: 'setbestdices',
            uriTemplate: '/sets/{id}/best/{x}',
            uriVariables:[
                'id' => new Link(
                    fromClass: Set::class
                )
            ],
            requirements: ['id' => '\d+', 'x' => '\d+'],
            controller: SetBestDicesController::class,
            openapi: new Model\Operation(
                summary: 'Get the x best dices', 
                description: 'Get a random value of each best dice', 
                responses: [
                    '200!!!' => new Model\Response(
                        description: "Dices value",
                        content: new \ArrayObject([
                            'application/json' => [
                                'schema' => [
                                    'type' => 'array',
                                    'description' => 'The value of each best dice'
                                ],
                                'example' => [
                                    6,3,1
                                ]
                            ]
                        ])
                    )
                ]
            )
        )
    ]
)]
```

With php bin/console debug:container --tag=roll I have :

```
Service ID Class name

kernel App\Kernel
App\Controller\RollController App\Controller\RollController
App\Controller\SetBestDicesController App\Controller\SetBestDicesController
App\Controller\SetRollDicesController App\Controller\SetRollDicesController
```

Why the first case is ok and not the second ? Can I create multiple get operation in the same entity ?

And another little problem is that I can't override the 200 response.

I have tried to put the "new Get setbestdices" in the same apiResource operation that 'setrolldices' but I had the same error.

I'd like to create several Get operations for my entity.

Thx for your help

Comment: You have new Get and net GetCollection, for the case you want a list instead of a single item.

Comment: In my case it was a custom controller with injected constructor arguments not properly tagged in services.yaml